# What differences should i make in the MPMoviePlayer sample code(for iphone) to make it work in Ipad?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, ipad

Its working perfectly in the iphone simulator. But not in the ipad simulator. I am only trying to make the movie getting loaded when the application launches.Copy pasted the same code in a ipad window application. But it loads and only gives the white screen and nothing is happening.

Can anyone tell me what changes should I make to work it in ipad simulator just as in the iphone simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view does need to be in a view hierarchy in order to be visible.  The sample code you're looking at probably sets up the view hierarchy in a nib rather than programmatically.  So make sure that you replicate the structure of the .xib files in the `Resources` group as well as the code.

Comment: Just added the view of the MPMoviePlayerController to my view and set fullscreen:animated. It worked perfectly. Thanks for your answer.